# Let $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$ exists finite, then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists finite too

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$ exists finite. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists finite too.

My work: since $f'(x) \to l \in \mathbb{R}$ as $x \to 0^+$, it follows that $f'$ is bounded in a right neighborhood of $0$; that is, there exists $\delta>0$ and there exists $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\le M$ for any $x\in(0,\delta)$. Since $f$ is differentiable, for the mean value theorem the inequality $|f'(x)|\le M$ for any $x\in(0,\delta)$ implies that $|f(s)-f(t)| \le M|s-t|$ for any $s,t \in (0,\delta)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. If $0<x_1<\epsilon/M<\delta$ and $0<x_2<\epsilon/M<\delta$ it follows that $|x_1-x_2|<\epsilon/M$ and $x_1,x_2 \in (0,\delta)$. So it holds:
$$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le M|x_1-x_2|<M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon$$
And this holds for any $\epsilon>0$ and for any $x_1,x_2 \in (0,\epsilon/M)$; for the Cauchy criterion for the limits of functions, this implies that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ exists finite.

Is this correct? I am not sure, in particular, if my choices of $0<x_1<\epsilon/M<\delta$ and $0<x_2<\epsilon/M<\delta$ are the correct ones. I chose them like these because I wanted to be sure that both the inequalities $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le M|x_1-x_2|$ and $|x_1-x_2|<\epsilon/M$ hold, but I am not sure if I am overdoing some steps and this wasn't necessary or this is how it should be done.

Comment: Once you establish that $f'$ is bounded on some $(1-\delta,1)$ then $f$ is Lipschitz on that interval. Then it maps any Cauchy sequence in that interval into a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The logic is perfectly sound, the only flaw I'm seeing is saying that "$\varepsilon/M < \delta$". However, taking the minimum between $\varepsilon/M$ and $\delta$ (and making the adequate changes) will correct that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose that $ f:I\rightarrow R $ is uniformly continuous--prove that the righthand limit at the endpoint exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146043/suppose-that-fi-rightarrow-r-is-uniformly-continuous-prove-that-the-righth)